# mysql join not working as expected

Tags: mysql, join

i want to select schedule of specific teacher for a given day  ....  statement should assume that a teacher may teach in elementary and high school

here is my statement

```
 `select 
   class.name as subject_classmodel_name, 
   teachers.name as subject_teachers_name, 
   section.name as subject_section_name, 
   day.name as day_name,
   time_format(time_range.time_start,'%H:%i') as time_time_start,
   time_format(time_range.time_end,'%H:%i') as time_time_end,
   sched.subject_ref, sched.time_ref, sched.day_ref
   from schedule sched
   join class_teachers_section
   join time_range
   join day
   join class
   join teachers
   join section
   where teachers.name = "ronald manlapao" and 
   section.level = "elementary" and 
   time_range.level = "elementary" and 
   class_teachers_section.id = sched.subject_ref and 
   class.id = class_teachers_section.class_ref  and 
   teachers.id = class_teachers_section.teachers_ref and 
   section.id = class_teachers_section.section_ref and
   day.id = sched.day_ref
   order by time_range.time_start asc`
```

class_teachers_section (table) has tables class, teachers, section
schedule (table) has tables class_teachers_section, day, time_range

output

[image]

expected result

only one row (last row) with time_start (14:00) time_end (15:00) should have data in columns subject_classmodel_name, subject_teachers_name, subject_section_name, subject_ref, time_ref and day_ref. the rest should be null

Im using MYSQL 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working because of you are missing "ON" statement

the right syntax is

```
SELECT field FROM tableA
JOIN tableB
ON tableA.id = tableB.id
```

Comment: May you describe what you are expecting for the result?

Comment: If you want to select specific range you can use this

WHERE time_start >= CAST('14:00' as time) AND time_end <= CAST('15:00' as time)

Comment: i want to select schedule of specific teacher for a given day  ....  statement should assume that a teacher may teach in elementary and high school

Comment: You can add Where statement that confirm that the teacher's name is same, WHERE teachername = teachername